# jQuery/Javascript Slider Previous Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Got small issue with my previous button. #prev it is not working it is not scrolling back to the previous image. It is scrolling to the next image. This is where i get my script from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

And also for some reason when I put width in for images say 100% it disappears

Also you can view live view of my slider here http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/JFgGb

```
$('#slider').cycle({ 
fx:     'scrollLeft', 
speed:  'slow', 
timeout: 5000, 
next:   '#next', 
prev:   '#prev'
});

<div class="page-wrapper">
<div class="controller" id="prev">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
</div>
<div id="slider">
<a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x300"></a>
<a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x300"></a>
<a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x300"></a>
</div>  
<div class="controller" id="next">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code pen is kind of useless as it is not showing the images.

Comment: My bad it is showing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check this [CodePan](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ouqFh)

### JS

```
$('#slider').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollLeft', 
    speed:  'slow', 
    timeout: 5000, 
    prev:   '#next'
});
$('#slider').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollRight', 
    speed:  'slow', 
    timeout: 5000, 
    next:   '#prev', 
});
```

Comment: the second and third images don't go full with I am not sure if its the image?